# Equivalence of norms and the inner product in $C([-1,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

In $\mathcal{C}([-1,1])$ we define:

$$\varphi_a(f,g)=\int_{-1}^{1} f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt+(2a^2-1)f(a)\overline{g(a)}, \ \ \ f,g\in\mathcal{C}([-1,1]), a\in[-1,1].$$

Let $\Lambda=\left\{a\in [-1,1]: \ \varphi_a \mathrm{ \ is \ an \ inner \ product}\right\}$. Compute the set $\Lambda$ and all pairs $(a,b)\in\Lambda\times\Lambda$, such that $\varphi_a$ and $\varphi_b$ set equivalent norms.

I know conditions to be the inner product, but I can't see how the parameter $a$ could ruin it. I think that the linearity should work, conjugate symetry too, only the 'positive-definitness' maybe, but it depends on so many things: on value of the integral, values $f(a)$,$g(a)$ and finally on the $sign\left\{ (2a^2-1)\right\}$, I don't know how to compute it.

Any hint how to start?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a\in [-1,1]$. For the positive-definiteness, you need $\varphi_a(f,f)\geq 0$ for all $f\in \mathcal{C}([-1,1])$.

The hint is to look at these two cases:

- $a$ such that $2a^2 - 1 \geq 0$.
- $a$ such that $2a^2 - 1 < 0$. In this case, consider the function $f_a$ s.t:

  $f_a(a)=1$, $f_a(x)$ is zero when $|x-a| \geq \frac{(1 - 2a^2)}{10}$, is a straight line in the interval $\left[a-\frac{(1 - 2a^2)}{10}, a\right]$ going from $0$ to $1$, and a straight line in the interval $\left[a, a+\frac{(1 - 2a^2)}{10}\right]$ going from $1$ to $0$.

What can you say about $\varphi_a(f_a,f_a)$ in this case?

Now, for the equivalence of the norms. Assume $a\ne b$. We have to look at these two cases:

- $a, b$ such that $2a^2 = 1 = 2b^2$. As you said, it is obvious the norms are equivalent in this case.
- $a, b$ such that either $2a^2 - 1 > 0$ or $2b^2 - 1 > 0$.

In this case, asume, w.l.o.g., $2a^2 - 1 > 0$. We will prove the norms are not equivalent in this case. One way to do this is to consider the sequence of functions $f_{a,n}$ s.t:

$f_{a,n}(a)=n$, $f_{a,n}(x)$ is zero outside of the interval $\left[a - \frac{1}{n^2}, a +\frac{1}{n^2}\right]$, is a straight line in the interval $\left[a-\frac{1}{n^2}, a\right]$ going from 0 to $n$, and a straight line in the interval $\left[a, a+\frac{1}{n^2}\right]$ going from $n$ to $0$.

Notice the function $f_{a,n}^2$ is nonzero only in a region included in a rectange of base $\frac{2}{n^2}$ and height $n^2$, whose area is $2$. Hence, $\varphi_b(f_{a,n}, f_{a,n})=\int_{-1}^1 f_{a,n}^2(x)dx\le 2$ for large enough $n$ s.t. $b$ is outside of the interval $\left[a - \frac{1}{n^2}, a +\frac{1}{n^2}\right]$.

On the other hand, $\varphi_a(f_{a,n}, f_{a,n})=\int_{-1}^1 f_{a,n}^2(x)dx + (2a^2 - 1) n^2 > (2a^2 - 1) n^2$ which goes to $+\infty$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Hence, for any constant $C>0$, we can find some $n$ s.t. $\varphi_a(f_{a,n}, f_{a,n}) > 2C \ge C\varphi_b(f_{a,n}, f_{a,n}) $. Hence, the norms are not equivalent.

Comment: I had to take some time to imagine how the function $f_a$ looks like. I'm still not shure, I mean, I see that we start in point $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ (arbitrarly close on the right from this point) and have value equal to $0$, then we have a pick with the top in $a$, and again zero to the point $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. I think that the value of integral will be between $(0,\frac{1}{100}]$ - maximal for $a=0$ and goes to $0$ when $a$ tends to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Therefore the second part $(2a^2-1)\cdot 1\cdot 1$ will give us the minus sign in the expression $\varphi_a(f_a,f_a)$. is that okay?

Comment: Yes, the point is that the value of the integral $\int_{-1}^1 f_a^2(x)dx=\int_{a-\frac{1-2a^2}{10}}^{a+\frac{1-2a^2}{10}} f_a^2(x)dx$ will be less than $(1 - 2a^2)$. One way to see this, is to realize the curve below the function $f_a^2$ is included in a rectangle of basis $\frac{1-2a^2}{5}$ and height 1, whose area is $\frac{1-2a^2}{5}$. Hence $\int_{-1}^1 f_a^2(x)dx\leq \frac{1-2a^2}{5}$.

Comment: I have this already, but now I have problem with showing equivalence of norms. Integrals can be canceled, I guess, so I have to consider: 

$m(2a^2-1)f^2(b)\le (2a^2-1)f^2(a)\le M(2a^2-1)f^2(b)$

Comment: Hi. I added an edit giving a hint for that part as well.

Comment: Thank you, the first case is obvious, but I don't know what have I do with the second one, in particular, why I need funtcion $f_{a,n}$, can you write more details?

Comment: Done. Sorry, I realized I made a small tipo previously.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is this some kind of standard construction for some type of problems or you created it just for this one? I'm asking cause this solution is very nice and in some sense very impressive for me!:)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you found the answer useful. As for your last question, I don't remember using or seeing much of this approach in my first analysis course. However, from what I recall, ideas like this are used in measure theory.